# Unable to display Toast message in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-toastr

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am trying to display toast message in Angular 5 using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr. I have downloaded required npm modules and copied css to assets folder. Also I have added

> import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

in app.component.ts.

I am trying to display toast message as

> this.toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');

When I run my solution I get below error.

[image]

When I run npm install, I get below warnings,

[image]
Can someone help me to figure out the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you imported **`ToastrModule`** in **`app.module.ts`**

```
import {ToastrModule} from 'ngx-toastr';
```

in your component, you need to import the provider

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
```

injector in the constructor as DI

```
constructor(public toastr: ToastrService) {}
```

And you can invoke it as

```
this.toastr.success(message, 'Success!');
```

**EDIT**

You need to move to angular6 inorder to make it work. Check the related issue **[`here`](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/547)**

Comment: Hi Thanks. I have already added all those steps and getting same error. I am using Angular 5. Do i need angular 6 here?

Comment: yes as it requirs rxjs 6 and above as you see in the error

Comment: How to upgrade it to rxjs6? In package.json I have   "rxjs": "5.5.5",

Comment: @Niranjan https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: I have installed rxjs. Now started getting error. I have added image above.

Comment: after looking at your error, it seems that you need to move to angular 6 .